# What does "to do the whole" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is the story from [this page](https://www.riddlesandanswers.com/tag/story-riddles/)

> 4 friends were walking home when they decided to take a shortcut
> through the woods. It begins to rain and they cannot find their way
> out of the woods since it becomes dark out. So they find a cabin and
> decide to stay in it till Morning. The cabin has no lights and no
> windows so it is pitch black. Scared, the 4 friends huddle together in
> the middle and decide to **do the whole**: 1 person stays awake to
> keep watch while everyone sleeps and they'd switch off every hour. But
> this plan didn't work as everyone was too scared to sleep. So they
> decided to play a game until sunrise. Each of the friends went into
> one of the four corners of cabin and played a game. one person would
> run out of their corner along the side of the cabin and tag the next
> person on their back and take their place. That person would then do
> the same as the last person and they would keep going at this till
> morning. They kept playing the game over and over till one of the
> friends realized something wrong and screamed. What did that person
> realize?

From the context I can gather that that means a certain kind of system of rules/actions that everyone agrees to follow/perform during a certain period of time. However, I didn't find "to do the whole" in Webster, so I am not sure.

Comment: The story is written in very bad English. You should ignore it.

Comment: As a native BrE speaker it is not a phrase I have ever seen written or heard spoken. Even in context I've no idea what it means.

Comment: Note that this story starts in the past tense "*were walking home*" then switches to the historical present "I*t begins to rain*" and  "*it becomes dark*" then shifts back to the past "*this plan didn't work*".  Then the author starts using an auxiliary "*would do*" then returns to the past Also the sentence "*Each of the friends went into one of the four corners of cabin and played a game*" implies that three were 4 separate games being played, but the next sentence makes it clear that there was only one involving all 4 people. I would not worry about the grammar in this text.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - Thank you!

Comment: @DavidSiegel - Thank you! In fact, I've learned from your comment such a thing like historical present. I've come across the usage of the present tense when clearly talking about the past and just couldn't understand what it was. Now I know that this kind of usage has a special name.

Comment: @brilliant See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present for more details on this form and when and how it is commonly used.